# A rook endgame from a classical book

Tags: analysis

From the game Kozul-Kurajica, Sarajevo 1998:

```
[FEN "2r3k1/5pp1/1p5p/3p4/8/P5P1/1P3PKP/4R3 w - - 0 0"]
```

In the above position; Stockfish 12 at a depth of 42 evaluates the position the position as +1.58 in Whites favour. With "Perfect Play" does the evaluation change significantly to give a definitive verdict.

Position from the book "Fundamental Chess Endings" - Müller & Lamprecht (2001) - Gambit Publications.

The game line was 1.Kf3 Kf8 (1...Rc2 2.Re2 wastes time, since the pawn ending is always lost) 2.Re3 Rc6 3.Rd3 Rd6 (3...Rc2 4.Rb3 loses) 4.Kf4 Re6 5.Kf3 (5.Rxd5 Re2 draws) Rd6 6.Ke3 Ke7 7.Kd4 Rf6 8.f3 Kd6 9.Re3 g5 10.a4 Re6? (decisive error by M/L; 10...h5 shall hold).

Comment: Could you please add the author, the publisher, the year of publication and the *correct* title? (*Fundamental Chess Ending* is not a grammatically correct title.)

Comment: Why do you show a diagram only to then talk about a completely different position? Which of the two is the one where Stockfish gives a +1.58 evaluation?

Comment: WHITE King on g2 Rook on e1 pawns on a3 b2 f2 g3 h2 BLACK King on g8 Rook on c8 pawns on b6 d5 f7 g7 h6 WHITE to move. FUNDAMENTAL CHESS ENDING.

Comment: This is from a famous game although I am struggling to remember who played. Capablanca ? Yusupov ? White won this game convincingly, but Black defense could be improved. Most probably the book's claim that Black can draw comes with an analysis, you should share the main lines/ideas and tell us which variation, or which evaluation you have doubts about.

Comment: @Evargalo currently cross referencing the position against my Reference Database(might take an hour or two). Fairly confident i'll get a hit from this; I'll let you know if i find it

Comment: I think there was a post the other day where the position required to be corrected as well...

@Tsundoku Book is actually "Fundamental Chess Endings" by  Müller & Lamprecht . Think the Publisher was Gambit??

Comment: Yeah there was a similar question raised the other day. I'll just do a GPU analysis. @Stefano , most computers are capable of analysing this position given 5 to 10 minutes. May i suggest you look into installing a chess program (eg SCID or chessbase) and installing StockFish?

Comment: Since FCE is just lying on my desk at the moment :-), I edited in some additional info.

Answer (score 1):

So doing a reference cross check I managed to locate the game from which this position is derived from. The position occurs at the end of move 25.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Sarajevo Bosnia 28th"]
[Site "Sarajevo"]
[Date "1998.05.31"]
[White "Kozul, Zdenko"]
[Black "Kurajica, Bojan"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "E00"]
[WhiteElo "2585"]
[BlackElo "2580"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. g3 Bb4+ 4. Nd2 c5 5. a3 Bxd2+ 6. Qxd2 cxd4 7. Nf3 d5 8. cxd5 exd5 9. Bg2 O-O 10. O-O Nc6 11. Nxd4 Re8 12. Nxc6 bxc6 13. Qc2 Ba6 14. Re1 Qb6 15. Bf4 Bc4 16. Rac1 h6 17. e4 Rac8 18. Be3 Qa6 19. exd5 Bxd5 20. Qc5 Bxg2 21. Kxg2 Nd5 22. Bd4 Rxe1 23. Rxe1 Qb6 24. Qxd5 cxd5 25. Bxb6 axb6 26. Kf3 Kf8 27. Re3 Rc6 28. Rd3 Rd6 29. Kf4 Re6 30. Kf3 Rd6 31. Ke3 Ke7 32. Kd4 Rf6 33. f3 Kd6 34. Re3 g5 35. a4 Re6 36. b4 Kc6 37. Rc3+ Kb7 38. Rc2 Rf6 39. Rf2 Rf5 40. b5 h5 41. Rf1 h4 42. Rf2 hxg3 43. hxg3 Kb8 44. g4 Rf4+ 45. Kxd5 Rxa4 46. Kc6 Ka7 47. Rc2 Ra3 48. f4 gxf4 49. Rc4 f3 50. Rf4 Rc3+ 51. Kd6 Kb8 52. Ke7 Kc7 53. g5 Rc5 54. Rxf7 f2 55. g6 Re5+ 56. Kf8+ Kd6 57. Rxf2 Rg5 58. Kf7 Kc5 59. Rf4 Kxb5 60. Kf6 Rxg6+ 61. Kxg6 Kc5 1-0
```

**Quick Visual Analysis:**

- Material is equal
- White has 2 pawn islands with a promotion threat on the A file in particular
- Black has 3 pawn islands.
- Whites Rook on the e file cuts the black king out of the game in the position , however white needs to activate the king and in doing so allows the black king to escape and join the play.

I would say given the position that white is winning but only slightly.

**Engine Analysis:**

Initial reports because the position had been reviewed multiple times.

- Deep Fritz Depth 22 = +0.48
- Houdini 4 x64 Depth 22 = +.041

I ran a StockFish 14 analysis on the position; which if you deem a engine as "Perfect Play" the position was drawn in most instances. However allowing it to run a bit longer; it appears that white can force the win.

```
[FEN "2r3k1/5pp1/1p5p/3p4/8/P5P1/1P3PKP/4R3 w - - 0 1"]
[Event "Sarajevo Bosnia 28th - Positional Analysis"]
[Site "Sarajevo"]
[Date "1998.05.31"]
[White "Stockfish 14"]
[Black "Stockfish 14"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "E00"]

1. Re3 Kf8 2. Kf3 g5 3. h3 h5 4. Re5 g4+ 5. hxg4 hxg4+ 6. Kxg4 Rc2 7. b4 Rxf2 8. Rxd5 Ke7 9. Re5+ Kf8 10. Re1 Kg7 11. Re8 Rd2 12. Kf4 Rf2+ 13. Ke3 Rg2 14. Kf3 Rc2 15. Re3 Rc4 16. Ke2 b5 17. Kd3 f6 18. Kd2 Rc8 19. Rc3 Ra8 20. Kc2 f5 21. Kb3 Kf6 22. Rc6+ Ke5 23. Rc5+ Ke4 24. Rxb5 Rg8 25. Ka4 Rxg3 26. Rb8 f4 27. Re8+ Kd3 28. Rf8 f3 29. b5 Ke2 30. b6 f2 31. b7 f1=Q 32. Rxf1 Rg4+ 33. Kb3 Rg3+ 34. Ka2 Rg8 35. Rb1 Rb8 36. Rb5 Kd3 37. a4 Kc4 38. Rb3 Kc5 39. a5 Kc4 40. a6 Rf8 41. b8=Q Rf2+ 42. Ka3 Rf6 43. Rb4+ Kd5 44. Qb5+ Ke6 45. Re4+ Kf7 46. Qe8+ Kg7 47. Rg4+ Kh7 48. Qg8+ Kh6 49. Rh4#
```

The engine at this point keeps going around in a circle and will eventually reach draw via threefold repetition.

Comment: What after 1 Re3 Kf8 2 Kf3 Rc6 reaching the same position of the book? It appeared Stockfish 14 have either ignored or refuted 2... Rc6. Just for curiosity, what was the depth of the analysis that grave the win to White?

Comment: At a depth of 60 it irrefutably gave the win the white then worked the move count down.

Comment: @Stefano the analysis lines are now up on the chessbase systems also. if you would like to review them.

Comment: My Stockfish 14 NNUE (now I also have it) give a win too. Depth = 55/90.Passing the second iteration at a critica Point (White has King, Rook and three pawns, Black has King, Rook and two pawns) for five minute, it already reached d= 70and the resulting Seven men endings results in a win for White. Thanks for confirming.